# how can i get div class name value of page from google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, extract

I want to write a chrome extension that will extract values from elements from in html (and may be inner html).

For instance, my page might have `<div class="title">my title</div>`

How do I extract "my title" in a chrome extension?

Comment: show us what youve tried and whats not working. look at content scripts

Answer (score 0):

You mean generally, how do you get the text of an element using its class name?

```
var element = document.querySelector(".title"); //'element' will be the first element on the page with the class "title"
var my_title = element.innerText; //'my_title' will be the text in that element
```

If you're asking how to make a Chrome extension in the first place, read this:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

The code above should be in the "content script" part of the extension. Content scripts are the part that can interact with web pages.

Comment: not working thru chrome extension.... it's working when i debug it on the web page with the console(F12) but not from the content

Comment: Is your content script set up correctly? Check if you can log anything from the content script. Have you declared it in the manifest?